# Apply Metal linear magnification filter only in the vertical direction

Tags: ios, metal

I have been working through Apple's Metal Tutorial, [Creating and Sampling Textures](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/creating_and_sampling_textures?language=objc).

The tutorial has shown me how to map a texture across a set of vertices and works well. My question is about the sampler in the fragment shader and the magnification filter.

It's important for the texture colours to not average out horizontally, but I would like them the be averaged vertically.

My fragment function is pasted below. Essentially I'd like `mag_filter::nearest` to be applied horizontally and `mag_filter::linear` to be applied vertically.

Is there any way to achieve this, or something like it?

```
fragment float4
samplingShader(RasterizerData in [[stage_in]],
               texture2d<half> colorTexture [[ texture(AAPLTextureIndexBaseColor) ]])
{
    constexpr sampler textureSampler (mag_filter::linear,
                                      min_filter::nearest);

    // Sample the texture to obtain a color
    const half4 colorSample = colorTexture.sample(textureSampler, in.textureCoordinate);

    // return the color of the texture
    return float4(colorSample);
}
```

Comment: I think it's possible to use the `gather` function and implement your own filtering. Alternatively, you could modify the UV coordinates so that `in.textureCoordinate`'s `y` component is clamped to the centre of a texel.